# FFMPEG unable to take frame and save as image

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm trying to save an image from a video frame and save it as a jpeg.
This function works for smaller video files, but if the video is over 10 minutes it won't save the jpeg image. An error comes up as before trans.

```
public function VideoToJpeg($localVideoPath, $localOutImgPath)
{
    $Name = dirname(__FILE__) . "/ffmpeg";
    $Str = "$Name -i \"$localVideoPath\" -an -ss 00:00:03 -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -y \"$localOutImgPath\"";

    exec($Str);
}
```

Here is the error I got from ffmpeg

```
[NULL @ 0370e760] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'path'
: Invalid argument
```

Comment: What is the error that comes up?

Comment: `An error comes up`?  And that error would be...?

Comment: Another part of the script is to encode any video fromat eg mp4 to a flv container and send it to the stream files of red5 .This works so I can see the image and the video plays properly.When the video is over ten minutes the image is not converted and in the streams directory a flv.beforetrans comes up under the video stream

Comment: You are still missing the full uncut output from FFmpeg

Comment: the -ss flag is used to denote start position, again in whole seconds or hh:mm:ss format.

Comment: ow i didnt mean for that to get there i deleted it . Wit hthe other anwser thanks for the link its very help full. The script works fine for any video codec under 10 minutes so when i run the two scripts I can see the image and it saves the image into the right path and transcodes the video but anything over 10 mintues it dosent work and  you can play the video but no jppeg image is created

Comment: Try logging the value of `$localOutImgPath`. See what the value comes out to be. I suspect it will be the string `"path"`.

Comment: Also, this is probably not what is causing the error, but you are adding a couple of unnecessary flags here. **1)** The second audio disable flag `-an` is not required. Just one will suffice. **2)** The framerate `r` flag is not required, since you are capturing a single frame

Comment: I totally changed the code and the image file is saved properly. But a new problem has comeup no audio should i post i post my new code that converts mp4 to flv

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear from your question but I think `$localOutImgPath` and `$localVideoPath` parameter are passing some wrong values as error said it clearly:

`[NULL @ 0370e760] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'path'`

kindly check it.

See [FFmpeg: The ultimate Video and Audio Manipulation Tool](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/) and
[FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help at all, but I have had success using the following PHP package (though I have never suffered from the issues you mention):

http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

Another alternative might be to change the php memory allocation setting:

http://drupal.org/node/207036

You are probably not using Drupal but most of the suggestions on that page are relevant and deal with PHP itself (rather than Drupal).